# Copy indices from Elasticsearch 5.x to 2.x - Reverting an upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, restore, elasticsearch-5, data-migration, elasticsearch-2.0

I tried upgrading our 2.x ES to 5.x and everything went fine, but then our app was still not ready to work with 5.x. I had to revert back to 2.x, which was fine, but the restore from the snapshot couldn't restore everything, so our data is missing now.

But, I had copied the 5.x index data over and it seems to have the missing data, how can I go about moving that data over to 2.x? I am running a new instance of 5.x  with all the data intact, is it even possible to copy over data like this?

Comment: if you have to distinct cluster you can try a remote reindex ( see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote  and here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-remote )

Comment: Actually I found a more suitable tool for this - called elasticdump - https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump